# How to stack probabilities to compare total outcomes

Tags: probability

A forum RPG I'm part of is working on a scaled/weighted rolling system for combat and other competitive skill checks, to prevent god-modding (a practice where players say their characters always win/succeed just because they want to). The idea is that based on an individual character's "level" they are assigned a specific HP value and a specific range for randomly generated scores, and various characters can roll against each other to determine a victor. These score ranges function as singular die rolls, and therefore have an equal chance of "rolling" any number within a given range.

For example,

Players A and B have decided to duel each other. Player A has 2 HP (meaning if they get "hit" twice, they lose) and has a score range of 1-20. Player B has 4 HP, and has a score range of 6-25. Both characters take turns "rolling" attack and defense (they randomly generate a number from within their individual score ranges, using a computer number generator) and those numbers are then compared against each other. So if A rolls a 15 attack and B rolls a 13 defense, B is "hit" and loses 1 HP. Since B has a range of 6-25, they are capable of rolling attacks that A is *not* capable of defending against, and likewise, A is capable of rolling attacks too low to succeed *even if* B rolls their minimum. Matching attack and defense rolls result in the attacker's favor. This continues until one character has 0 HP left.

I know how to calculate the odds of any given roll being successful from either side, but not how to calculate out the odds of a full game going either way. How do I calculate what the chances are that A makes 4 successful attacks *before* B makes 2 successful attacks?

Once I know how to solve this problem with one set of numbers, I can apply the process to the rest of the various lineups. I basically just want to see how balanced and smooth the current scaling system is.

What I have so far:

If A rolls a 1 on their attack, there are 0 out of B's 25 possible rolls that result in B getting hit, for a 0% success chance. If A rolls a 6, there is a 1/25 chance that B gets hit. And so on. Since each of A's possible rolls has a 1/20 (5%) chance of occurring, I added all of the possible hit chances together and divided by 20 for an overall 24% chance to hit B on any given round. Doing the same process with B's possible rolls, they get a 79% chance to hit A on any given round.

I'm just not sure what to do to find the odds of an indefinite number of rounds that continues until someone has been hit a specific number of times.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Apologies, I was afraid adding the context would be superfluous and bother people. I'll add a bit more explanation.

Comment: You need to explain this to math people not all of whom play role playing games. I don't know what a "score range" is, and I'm pretty sure many others on this site don't either. Please define any non-mathematical terms that you make essential use of.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying...

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Do the characters attack each other alternately? Or is the same player always attacking?

Comment: They alternate. Which goes first is decided by a coin toss. If A goes first, then it looks like,

A attacks and B defends,
B attacks and A defends,
A attacks, etc etc

Answer (score 1):

First, work out the probabilities of A hitting B, and of B hitting A. You said you know how to calculate these probabilities, so we'll skip calculating them. The important point is that these probabilities are the same each turn.

A attacks on every odd turn and B attacks on every even turn. We can pretend that the game continues forever, so even if A dies, play continues (pointlessly, since A can no longer win). By adopting this perspective the math becomes fairly simple. The game is seen to be equivalent to a game in which A and B go into separate rooms and roll attack rolls, and each sees how many rolls it takes them before they "would have" killed the other player (i.e. if my opponent has 5 HP, I keep rolling until I score 5 hits). Then they meet up and reveal how many rolls they took to "win". The winner of the fight is whoever got the lowest number of rolls.

If I have a probability of hitting $p$ times, then the number of rolls taken to score one hit is modeled by a [geometric random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Related_distributions) with parameter $p$. If I have to score $n$ hits (my opponent has $n$ HP) then my total number of rolls will be the sum of $n$ independent geometric random variables of parameter $p$, [will be given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Related_distributions) a [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) with parameters $n$ and $p$.

So we have two negative binomials with parameters $(n_B, p_A)$ and $(n_A, p_B)$, where $n_i$ is player $i$'s initial HP and $p_i$ is player $i$'s chance to hit when they attack. Referring to these negative binomials as $X$ and $Y$ respectively, the question is, what is the probability that $X\leq Y$? This corresponds to the event that A wins. (Notice that A attacks first, so when $X=Y$, A wins)

So your problem is equivalent to the question:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are two independent negative binomial variables, what is the probability that $X\leq Y$?

I don't know if this problem can be solved cleanly. You could try writing it out as an infinite sum and seeing if it can be computed algebraically.

Answer (score 0):

If a 'fights' b. If we call each dice roll a round then for each round the proabaility of a 'winning' that round is A and b winning is B = 1-A.

if a has 2 HP and b has 4 HP then we want to know what is the probability of a scoring 4 hits before b scores 2. Or equivalently what is the probability that a gets at least 4 hits in the first 5 rounds. (I know the fight might not last the whole 5 rounds but for our purposes we can assume it always does as the winner would never be affected). This equals the probability of a getting 4 hits + the probability of a getting 5 hits or:

${5\choose4} A^4 B + {5\choose5} A^5B^0$

Comment: ...What? B doesn't need a score of 5. B needs a score of 2. Where are you getting the 5 from? I don't understand anything of your equation, either...

Comment: the 5 was a mistake I meant to put 2.

Comment: Okay, but you still have a bunch of 5's in the equation, and I still don't understand where that's coming from. Why five rounds? How is that "equivalent"?

Comment: Because after 5 rounds one of the players must be dead. So the fight can be a maximum of 5 rounds long.

Comment: Incorrect. A hit isn't guaranteed every round. Each player rolls one attack and one defense score. The odds are very, *very* slim, but it is perfectly possible for both players to roll higher defense scores every round, resulting in nobody getting hit at all for five rounds, or only getting hit once.

Comment: Ah I see, I misunderstood the question in that case my apologies, I thought if the defence roll was higher then the attacker would lose a hp point